# I facing a problem when i want create two registration forums by using (profile2 & profile2 registration path) modules?

Tags: 7, users

i want create two registration forums ,each forum in specific page , when i looking for solution in internet, i found it using profile2 & profile2 registration path modules.

But when i working in it , i facing a new problem , the problem is the users can't find registration forums ,because they doesn't have a link or (way to access in forums ) for registration !?

Example :

i have two roles A & B.

URL path for A : {mysite/A/register}

URL path for B : {mysite/B/register]

When user A click on page to create new account can't going to {mysite/A/register} link !!!

Any ideas ??

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Fully not clear problem but you can try by this way

Hook: user A, user B
User: user-profile.tpl.php

if((arg(A)=='user') && is_numeric(arg(1)))
{
$profile = profile2_load_by_user(arg(1));